# Stop SAS Enterprise Guide 8.3. showing results automatically

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

How do I stop EG 8.3. from automatically downloading results after running my code?
In EG 7 this functionality was in a checkbox:

```
Options>Results>Results General>Automatically Open Data or results when generated
```

Now I can't find it :(

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/egdoccdc/8.2/egug/n1vbf8931fo6x2n1v0rizzuuz81u.htm

Comment: Try: Tools>Options>Projects and Process Flows>Show generated results

Comment: No matter if the checkbox is active or not, datasets are still automatically opening after running SAS code :(
I assume it only applies to process flow runned branches and programs?

Comment: Results and data sets are not the same thing. To suppress the data sets from opening see the options under Data>Preference https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/egdoccdc/8.2/egug/n1bcs58sfe6dw7n144uhawywkllv.htm

Comment: I found this dropdown menu under Options>Data>Performance>When output tables, automatically open>No table. Thank you :)